# chrome different than Internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I looked for a similar question but no solutions.

I have a webpage with a table and a Youtube movie at the middle: http://www.zofim.org.il/magazin_item.asp?item_id=531438084004

it looks good in Chrome, but in Internet explorer the movie is too low and not in the right place.

Here is the code:

```html
<table background="http://www.zofim.org.il/pics/magazin/Page-1 (1).jpg" width="650" height="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="0" width="600">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;                         </span>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;</span></p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;</span></p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;</span></p>
                    <p><br />
                    &nbsp;</p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;</span></p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; ">&nbsp;</span></p>
                    <p><span style="font-size: 8; "><br />
                    <br />
                    <br type="_moz" />
                    </span></p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="440" width="23%" rowspan="2">
                    <table border="0" width="100%" height="430">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="131">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="63"><a href="http://zofim.org.il/magazin_item.asp?item_id=531477450625&amp;troop_id=285610000">                                     <img border="0" src="http://www.zofim.org.il/pics/magazin/1(158).gif" width="134" height="76" alt="" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    <td height="142" width="12%">
                    <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                    </td>
                    <td height="142" width="35%">
                    <p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; "><iframe width="250" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wnBGKeXF8X0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" name="I1" scrolling="no" marginheight="2"></iframe></p>
                    </td>
                    <td height="142" width="31%">&nbsp;
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="285" colspan="3">
                    <table border="0" width="100%" height="292">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="135">
                                <table border="0" width="100%" height="280">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="78"><a href="http://zofim.org.il/magazin_item.asp?item_id=531516818704&amp;troop_id=285610000">                                     <img border="0" src="http://www.zofim.org.il/pics/magazin/1(158).gif" width="134" height="99" alt="" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <table border="0" width="104%" height="278">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="78"><a href="http://zofim.org.il/magazin_item.asp?item_id=531556188241&amp;troop_id=285610000">                                     <img border="0" src="http://www.zofim.org.il/pics/magazin/1(158).gif" width="175" height="99" alt="" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="153">
                                <table border="0" width="100%" height="281">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="78"><a href="http://zofim.org.il/magazin_item.asp?item_id=531595559236&amp;troop_id=285610000">                                     <img border="0" src="http://www.zofim.org.il/pics/magazin/1(158).gif" width="152" height="99" alt="" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

thanks!

Dor.

Comment: Your markup is horrible. Use CSS for layout/styling!

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the markup you provided you are using tables to layout your website. This is considered bad practice. You should consider changing to using best practices (divs etc) and using CSS to style your layout instead of using inline-styles. When you have done this you can use [prefixr.com](http://prefixr.com) to create cross-browser friendly CSS.